# Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008-sp1

A while ago, i did a little course about the 3.5 framework. There a mechanism in VS2008 to keep track of the users logged, their roles..., and there are some sql files that create the tables' structure needed to keep track of users, roles..., and this files are installed in the during the instalation of vs2008, but I cannot find it. Can anyone remind me the name of this mechanism or point me to the right direction to find the info that I need... I hope my explanation helps, many thanks for your help guys

Comment: You may want to edit the title of the question so it is a question. "Visual Studio 2008" isn't going to direct a lot of folks your way.

Answer (score 0):

From a visual studio Command prompt run

aspnet_regsql and complete the wizard

Comment: it's actually installed by either .NET or the .NET SDK, it's located in the framework dir, for VS2008 this means `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\V2.0.50727\`